# Moodle html editor loads very slow

Tags: editor, moodle

i have 2 servers with the exact same moodle installation and configuration.
One server is 4 cores and 16 ram and the other is 8 cores and 32 ram.

The 4x16 editor in moodle loads in 1 minute and the 8x32 loads in 6 or 7 minutes and its frustrating.

I already review the php.ini to see the differences between servers and are minimal (not critical to this matter).

I dont know what else i can do, does anybody knows what should i look out?
Thanks!

I have moodle 2.5 and both are CentOS

Answer (score 0):

The editor in Moodle is TinyMCE

http://docs.moodle.org/25/en/Text_editor

I'm not sure why its slow though. You might want to ask the question on the TinyMCE forum?

http://www.tinymce.com/forum/

Also found this on the Moodle forums, so it might be a new issue

https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=232089

There is an alternative editor in the plugins, maybe test that, see if Moodle is still slow.

https://moodle.org/plugins/browse.php?list=category&id=23